# Replication advice Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, replication

We have a requirement to implement replication (of transactions) from a production database to a test database (across a db link). We're using 11g enterprise edition.

This is because it's not just the production data that's needed, the intention is that code releases in the test database would be tested against real-world transactions from the prod system, without the need for those transactions to be done manually. If a transaction fails then in the test system that worked in the prod system, something is wrong with the release.

It doesn't necessarily have to be in real-time however, a delay is acceptable.

There must be zero risk though on the production transactions failing, due an issue with the replication.

What are the options here? I believe Streams is deprecated in 12c, should that be of concern? GoldenGate is additional ££, which I'm afraid rules it out in this case. Some kind of custom trigger-based solution... too much risk on the prod system as far as I can see.

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are many tool available for data replication. One of them is Delphi. Check out once.

Comment: Maybe better to ask this in http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

As of Oracle release 12c (12.1.x), Oracle Advanced Replication and Oracle Streams are being discontinued. Oracle Golden Gate is going to replace all features of Oracle Advanced Replication and Oracle Streams.

Please review this list of possible alternatives (to name a few):

```
SharePlex
DBVisit
DBConvert
```